# Sentence paraphrase spilt small sntences

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-usage

Can anyone paraphrase this sentence for me. I am not a native speaker. It will be easy for me to understand the sentence if someone spilt it small sentences.

`The Dictionary, together with his other writing, made Johnson famous and so well esteemed that his friends were able to prevail upon King George III to offer him a pension.`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dictionary (and his other writing) made Johnson famous. He was so well thought of that his friends managed to persuade King George III to offer him a pension.

I can't make the sentences any shorter than that!

Comment: Thanks for paraphrasing. However, prevail means prove more powerful or superior.

Comment: Yes, but _prevail upon_ means _persuade_ (that is, your wishes are 'more powerful' than the other person's). https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/prevail-on?q=prevail+upon